# I'm seeing spurious characters appear in header row when using DictReader() on an open CSV file

Tags: python

When I open a csv file with a header row for reading, when I use DictReader() the first K:V entry contains the header text along with some extra characters.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
devicelist =  "HubDeviceList.csv"
 
# open device file
input_file = open( infilepath + devicelist, "r" , encoding="utf-8")

#Open CSV and create dictionary 
csvreader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
 
# loop through device list and execute commands
for ip in csvreader:
    print(ip)
```

The .csv contains:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjHiZ.png)

But the print statement shows the site name to be:
\ufeffSite

This is something to do with the encoding as if I change that statement in the open() statement I get different characters, can I remove them or perhaps I'm not using the correct encoding?

I tried altering the encoding which altered the extra text that appeared, but I could do without it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try `open()` with the encoding set to `encoding='utf-8-sig'`. I believe that is the BOM.

Comment: encoding='utf-8-sig fixed it thanks! And yes, I get the point about uploading images, I'm new to Stack Overflow, I didn't expect the platform to do that!
Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

Your utf8 input file regrettably has a
[BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
It should not.
Correct the software which produced that file.
We place a byte-order-mark at the beginning of
fixed format filetypes like UTF-16,
but not for variable length glyph encodings like UTF-8.

To work around this error,
you can specify an encoding which matches the input:

```
input_file = open(infilepath + devicelist, "r" , encoding="utf-8-sig")
```